# Unhandled Exception while Get a Response from Web API in Xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, asp.net-web-api2

I am creating my first xamarin project with PCL .

I have created WebApi2 with Get Response and publish on  my local server which works fine and provides the JSON response correctly

**URL : http://test.propertytaxapi.com/api/ward**

response : 
[{"id":1,"zone_id":1,"ward_no":"1"},{"id":2,"zone_id":1,"ward_no":"2"},{"id":3,"zone_id":1,"ward_no":"3"},{"id":4,"zone_id":1,"ward_no":"4"},{"id":5,"zone_id":1,"ward_no":"5"},{"id":6,"zone_id":1,"ward_no":"6"}]

but when i tried to implement this in my Xamarin project and call it like.

```
public async Task<List<Ward>> GetData()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://test.propertytaxapi.com/api");
                    var response = await client.GetAsync("ward");
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    var placesJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    Ward wardData = new Ward();
                    if (placesJson != "")
                    {                      
                        var wlists= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Ward>>(placesJson);
                        wardList = wlists.ToList();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {                   
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return wardList;
        }
```

I got the exception on this line :-
**var response = await client.GetAsync("ward");**

**Exception:**

11-02 14:11:29.968 E/mono    ( 2954): 
11-02 14:11:29.968 E/mono    ( 2954): Unhandled Exception:
11-02 14:11:29.968 E/mono    ( 2954): System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure
11-02 14:11:29.968 E/mono    ( 2954):   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00058] in <6c708cf596db438ebfc6b7e012659eee>:0 
11-02 14:11:29.968 E/mono    ( 2954):   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
11-02 14:11:29.968 E/mono    ( 2954): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
11-02 14:11:29.968 E/mono    ( 2954):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
11-02 14:11:29.968 E/mono    ( 2954):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
11-02 14:11:29.968 E/mono    ( 2954):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
11-02 14:11:29.968 E/mono    ( 2954):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
11-02 14:11:29.968 E/mono    ( 2954):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
11-02 14:11:29.968 E/mono    ( 2954):   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__63.MoveNext () [0x00450] in <7736395a6c71409691a34accfc621095>:0 
11-02 14:11:29.968 E/mono    ( 2954):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
11-02 14:11:29.976 E/mono-rt ( 2954): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure
11-02 14:11:29.976 E/mono-rt ( 2954):   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00058] in <6c708cf596db438ebfc6b7e012659eee>:0 
11-02 14:11:29.976 E/mono-rt ( 2954):   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
11-02 14:11:29.976 E/mono-rt ( 2954): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
11-02 14:11:29.976 E/mono-rt ( 2954):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
11-02 14:11:29.976 E/mono-rt ( 2954):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
11-02 14:11:29.976 E/mono-rt ( 2954):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
11-02 14:11:29.976 E/mono-rt ( 2954):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
11-02 14:11:29.976 E/mono-rt ( 2954):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
11-02 14:11:29.976 E/mono-rt ( 2954):   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__63.MoveNext () [0x00450] in <7736395a6c71409691a34accfc621095>:0 
11-02 14:11:29.976 E/mono-rt ( 2954):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Please suggest me the solution to get response

Answer (score 1):

client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://test.propertytaxapi.com/api/");

Add backslash at the end of Base address. Try the above uri